# How to retrieve all my comments in other YouTube videos like "my-comments" in Google Takeout?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

How to retrieve all my comments in other YouTube videos like "my-comments" in Google Takeout?
I want list all my YT comments to Google spreadsheet via Apps Script

Comment: AFAIK YouTube Data API v3 doesn't provide any way to meet your needs. However I may have a workaround, could you contact me on [Discord](https://discord.gg/pDzafhGWzf) to see [some details](https://discord.com/channels/933841502155706418/933841503103627316/937865558945304596) ?

Comment: If you find a way to send requests to youtube using web-scrapping *with your credentials*, you could *then* web-scrap your own data - [I made a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69453515/12511801), but, without any results yet. Search about how to make requests from google spreadsheets and sending your credentials (*or logging on in the destinty website*) and then you can proceed further.

Comment: Finally [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76955655) to this question is available.